# Splitting a dataframe if rows are numeric or not in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (let's call it 'df') it consists of two columns

```
 Name   Contact
 A      34552325
 B      423424
 C      4324234242
 D      hello1@company.com
```

I want to split the dataframe into two dataframe based on whether a row in column "Contact" is numeric or not

Expected Output:

```
 Name   Contact
 A      34552325
 B      423424
 C      4324234242
```

and

```
 Name   Contact
 D      hello1@company.com
```

I tired using:

```
   df$IsNum <- !(is.na(as.numeric(df$Contact)))
```

But this classified "hello1@company.com" also as numeric.

Basically if there is even a single non-numeric value in column "Contact", then code must classify it as non-numeric

Comment: You probably have factors there, so just `as.numeric` won't work, Try `split(df, is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df$Contact))))` maybe

Comment: for me worked your approach, after I did `df$Contact <- as.vector(df$Contact)`. I also did like this `df$IsNum <- suppressWarnings({!(is.na(as.numeric(df$Contact)))})` in order to get rid of the `warning message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `grepl`..

```
x <- " Name   Contact
 A      34552325
 B      423424
 C      4324234242
 D      hello1@company.com"
df <- read.table(text=x, header = T)
x <- df[grepl("^\\d+$",df$Contact),]
y <- df[!grepl("^\\d+$",df$Contact),]
x
#   Name    Contact
# 1    A   34552325
# 2    B     423424
# 3    C 4324234242
y
#  Name            Contact
# 4    D hello1@company.com
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a grouping variable with `grepl` (same as how @Avinash Raj created), `split` the dataframe with that to create a `list` of data.frames.

```
split(df, grepl('^\\d+$', df$Contact))
```